# Android OpenGL ES ortho strange aspect ratio

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm quite new to OpenGL ES and I'm trying to draw some textured quads. I want to keep it 2D so I decided to use orthographic projection. What I really want is to draw a plane that takes the same relative amount of screen space on every device regardless the screen resolution.

The problem I encounter is the setup of the orthographic projection. The aspect ratio just isn't correct. A square is drawn as a rectangle in the height. This is my code so far:

The Renderer:

```
// automatically looped by android
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    // clear screen and buffer
    gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 

    // Draw elements
    for (GameObject object : level.getGameObjects()) {
        gl.glScalef(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.0f);
        object.draw(gl);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }
}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    gl.glOrthof(0f, 480f, 0f, 800f, -1f, 1f);

}

public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    // Load all textures
    for (GameObject object : level.getGameObjects()) {
        object.bindTexture(gl);
    }

    // Initialize game canvas
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D); // Enable Texture Mapping
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f); // Black background

    // enable texture transparency
    gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA,   GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);               
}
```

The draw method is exactly the same as in this tutorial: http://obviam.net/index.php/texture-mapping-opengl-android-displaying-images-using-opengl-and-squares/

Kind regards,
Daan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer to my problem. First of all I was hardcoding the width and height wich wasn't a good option. To have a fixed with on all screen resolutions i now calculate the aspect ratio and for the height I use the with multiplied by the aspect ratio.

Another problem was the fact that I hadn't reset the projection matrix prior to setting the glortho. I have changed all this and it solved the problem:

```
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {      
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glOrthof(0f, 320, 0f, 320*aspect, -1f, 1f);
}
```

I hope this will be helpfull for somebody.

Kind regards,
Daan

Comment: Hi Daan, would this particular orthographic projection allow me to draw a line from the top left corner of the device screen to the bottom right by using `drawline(0, 0, 320, 320*aspect)` where `drawline` is my line drawing code. I want to know if the glOrthof parameters basically set my gl screen bounds, i.e. is my screen "canvas" for drawing bounded by the gl coords `[0,320]x[0,320*aspect]` ? Or will this depend on `glViewport` also?

Answer (score 2):

Why are you hardcoding the width and height to glOrthof? Shouldn't you use the passed in width and height?

`gl.glOrthof(0f, width, 0f, height, -1f, 1f);`

Comment: Thank you, this was one of the causes of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've solved it. Can you provide details on how you calculated the aspect variable (a division of height and width perhaps?) Just as an FYI, the height and width values passed in to the onSurfaceChanged() event are indeed dynamic. For instance, they are reversed when you flip the screen orientation. 
I'm relatively new to this as well, but in my desktop gl experience, it's important to factor these in when a window size changes.